# Find and move unknown word between particular characters in the string C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, sorting

I'm trying to find and move unknown word between particular characters in the string in C#.
Example:

```
// this is a string from the file
begining of the string - "    TASK PERS partdata pd_Test_05:=["Call_Test_05","Test_05","T_ROB1",1,0,"",""];" - end of the string.
// I insert that string inside the string[] lines.
// I need to found and seperate word "Test_05" from that string.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to do something like this:

`List<string> test = yourString.Split(',').ToList<string>();`

`string finalProduct = test[1];`

At this point, your string would look like `"Test_05"`. Just replace the quotation marks with C#'s [replace](https://www.dotnetperls.com/replace) or Regex replace them.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your answer(s), you can [contact](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fhelp) SO and ask them to anonymise your questions/answers

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to know how to give an answer, we dont know what makes Test_05 the particular target.

As a general guide you can either use Regular expressions if the target string matches a pattern. You might find this site useful http://regexstorm.net/

Or you can use string operations like IndexOf (search for a given string in a string), Substring (slice out a piece of a string), Replace,...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks GMR516.
I finished with 'Trim.

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("testFile.mod");
        List<string> test = lines[0].Split(',').ToList<string>();

        string finalProduct = test[1].Remove(1, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"Before trim: {finalProduct}");

        char[] charsToTrim = { '*', ' ', '\'', '"' };
        // Trim method can remove any characters from specified string
        string result = finalProduct.Trim(charsToTrim);

        Console.WriteLine($"After Trim: {result}");
```